# What does Not and Is Nothing do in this code?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code sees if there is a value in "A2" cell, then it clears the values in "C1".

Can someone explain me what does `Not` and `Is Nothing` do is the following code?

I need to change this code to work vice Versa, which I can only do if I can understand the code properly.

If some one can help me that would be good.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried the following:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    Else
         If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
             Range("A2").ClearContents
         End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: [`Not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/not-operator) is a boolean logical operator for an expression, and `Is Nothing` means "is null".  So I believe that can translate simply to "if the range is not null, clear the contents of C1"

Comment: I've modified the indenting of your second piece of code: it's much more readable if nested if-loops are clearly visible as such (no two subsequent `End If` lines where you can't see which one belongs to which original `If`-loop).

Comment: The second code is Giving me a Runtime error:28  
Code seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyse this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

This is an event, which is launched when something changes in a worksheet. The place where the changes appear is the so-called `Target`.

That `Target` can contain just one cell, or multiple cells (it's possible to modify different cells, it's also possible that cells contain a formula, whose result changes, together with some other changes, ...).

We would like to know if there are any changes in the cell "A2", how to do that?
Simple: we take the intersection of the `Target` and cell "A2". Two possibilities: either it contains something or not. If it contains something, then you can say that that intersection is not nothing.

So, by checking if the intersection of the `Target` and cell "A2" is not nothing, you can check if anything has been changed in cell "A2".